# How to run VS code on more than one monitor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm still new to VS code and I saw this type of using VS code on two monitors, so I have 3 monitors and I'm on Windows 10. I use the left one as a preview for the code I'm typing in Chrome so that's sorted and I want my middle one to have the main code I'm working on.

My right one is set up vertically so I want it to run the terminal for that file or another file so I can use both my right and middle to write code. I have no idea how I can do this.

Comment: 'ctrl + k' followed by 'o' - will open the current file in a new window. Then drag this window to your vertical display

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code - Tabs (editors) of the same project in multiple screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47260995/visual-studio-code-tabs-editors-of-the-same-project-in-multiple-screens)

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in latest VS Code.
Now you can even debug on seperate window.

1.Right click on the "tab" in question.

2. Select "Move into New Window"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recently was looking for a way to do this myself and came across this post without an answer.  The comment on the first post is a great hint.  So here is what I found:

1. Open your project in VS Code.  Make this your main window that you will have the terminal open, your file listing, debugging.
2. To open an individual file to work on, use the method @starfish gave, select the file, then use the key sequence "ctrl+k" then press "o", or "cmd+k", then "o".
3. Arrange the two windows to your liking on one or more monitors.

The second window does not inherit the folder you opened originally, but you can drag files from the original VS Code window and drop them in this new window.

Why is this needed?  If you have a folder open in a VS Code window and then try starting a new instance of VS Code and opening the same folder, it just switches to the original window.  At least that is what happens on my Mac.  This is the only workaround I have found without investigating every possible setting.

Comment: Do the 2 windows somehow communicate? For example for running code, debugging from the individual file? Or do you always need to switch to the main window in order to execute something?

Comment: @EricDuminil, The second window does have the debug tools.  It does not have the Explorer of Git information from the original window.  It is as if you open a single file instead of a folder.

Answer (score 0):

there is a workaround, first in the file you want to open go and click ctrl+shift+p and search for open active file in new window, then in your new instance, press again ctrl+shit+p and search for Open User Settings(JSON) and add this line at the end of the settings "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange", so whenever you change windows the current file you're working on will be auto saved, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + Shift + N create new window and drag and drop your file into the new window.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).